# spring cloud config propertySources "name" changed

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

when migrating from

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>
```

to

`Greenwich.SR2 (aka 2.1.3.RELEASE)`

I wrote a simple script to compare the config returned by both servers (to validate before converting).  My script is failing because the propertySources "name" field changed:

It *used* to return:

`"name": "git@my-server:MyOrg/central-config.git/some-application.yml#dev"`

but **now** returns:

`"name": "git@my-server:MyOrg/central-config.git/some-application.yml (document #3)"`

IE `#dev` is now `(document #3)` which is much less valuable when debugging configs.

I understand I can ignore the `name` in the test, but I'd like to get the old format back for usability's sake.

was this by design?
Is there anyway to configure this back?

UPDATE:

before the upgrade:
[image: before the upgrade]

after the upgrade:
[image: after the upgrade]

Comment: Not be design. There's not a way to get it back. Definitely not a contract to be relied upon.

Comment: I guess I'm confused.  When did this break, cause it _used_ to work.  Also, how is "(document #3)" of any value?  Isn't application.yml#dev much more valuable?

Comment: No one has complained about it yet and it is just an informational string. Feel free to log an issue, PRs welcome.

Comment: @spencergibb - can you point me to the code base where that message is being generated.  I suspect you have a decent idea of "where to start".  If you could share that with me, it would jumpstart my ability to get a PR created.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Rationalize multi-document config file handling (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/c0d79b92735b46010fb922a214b4cbb20c07fda5) is the commit that changed the behavior.

While it appears that people with bigger brains then me wanted to make this change, it seems counter productive to debugging where your config values came from.  I feel like I'm missing some piece of knowledge.  Does the `(document #0)` suffix actually have some value I'm unaware of?

Comment: It is the document number in the yaml file that has multiple documents in it. It's a boot change. You can ask for a change there.